# How can i get the same instance of quartz scheduler both in Java and C#?

Tags: java, c#, quartz-scheduler

My quartz scheduler has been started by a java program (As a windows service). Now I need to get the same scheduler instance through a c# client. Always I get a new instance of scheduler rather than the created/started one by java.

**Quartz property in C# code :**

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestSyncScheduler";
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "TestSyncId";

// set thread pool info
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "10";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName"] = "SyncScheduler";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType"] = "tcp";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://127.0.0.1:1100";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
```

**Quartz property in Java code :**

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: TestSyncScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: TestSyncId
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.createRegistry = true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost = 127.0.0.1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort = 1200
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.serverPort = 1100
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=false
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName=quartz:type=QuartzScheduler,name=SyncScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

**Problem** : How can I get the same instance of quartz scheduler with given properties both in Java and C# ?

Comment: What do you mean with "same"? If you mean that c# and java use an object at the same memory address that behaves exactly the same in c# context and in jvm context I think this seems impossible. Or your question is missing lots of context.

Comment: Isn't Quartz running in the JVM ? How do you expect C# to use that thread ? Well you could always create your own bridge to be able to fire event to a C# using Java. Or maybe there is a way to use Quartz outside of the JVM, and then maybe share a process. But I found that unlikely (but I don't know it enough). Interesting question !